# Creating list of hours separated by 30 min in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create this list in c#, add this is what I am at now

[image]

```
public static List<string> GetCurrentTime()
    {
        var start = DateTime.Today;
        List<string> L = new List<string>();
        var clockQuery = from offset in Enumerable.Range(0, 48)
                         select start.AddMinutes(30 * offset);
        foreach (var time in clockQuery)
            L.Add(time.ToString("hh:mm"));

        return L;
    }
```

This code will generate this list, and I am stuck here, how can I generate the above list which the first value should always start (1 hour after now - 1 hour 30min)

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: Say it's currently 13:00 (1PM) should the first generated time be 14:00 or 12:30? 14:00 because `1 hour after now`, 12:30 because `1 hour after now - (minus) 1.5 hours`

Comment: it should be 14:00 - 14:30

Comment: Start from `Now` rather than `Today` and iterate until the date changes?

Comment: ok but how can i group them?

Comment: `L.Add($"{time.ToString("hh:mm")} - {time.AddMinutes(30).ToString("hh:mm")});`?

Comment: Ok, then what if the time is in between hours, like say it's 13:17, should the next time be `14:17 - 14:47` or should it round (up) to the nearest full hour (15:00) or to the next nearest half hour (14:30)?

Comment: it should be round up to 15:00 - 15:30 i guess

Comment: Add this in foreach loop   L.Add(time.ToString("hh:mm") + "-" + time.AddMinutes(30).ToString("hh:mm"));

Answer (score 0):

I set my code like the following:

```
public static List<string> GetCurrentTime()
    {
        var start = DateTime.Today;
        List<string> L = new List<string>();
        var clockQuery = from offset in Enumerable.Range(0, 48)
                         select start.AddMinutes(30 * offset);
        foreach (var time in clockQuery)
        {
            if(time > DateTime.Now)
            {
                L.Add(time.ToString("hh:mm") + " - " + time.AddMinutes(30).ToString("hh:mm"));
            }
        }
            

        return L;
    }
```

This will result to the following list and it worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want time from mid-night :

```
 public static List<string> GetCurrentTime()
 {
   var now = DateTime.Now;
   var start = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
   List<string> L = new List<string>();
   var clockQuery = from offset in Enumerable.Range(0, 48)
                   select start.AddMinutes(30 * offset);
  foreach (var time in clockQuery)
   {
     L.Add(time.ToString("hh:mm") + "-" + 
           time.AddMinutes(30).ToString("hh:mm"));
   }
  return L;
}
```